# Unable to print a function's parameter outside function even when returned

Tags: lua, love2d

Contents is a table which is passed as a parameter for the function `func`. The issue is that I'm unable to print out any value from the table `contents`. For example here you can see I was trying to print the 2nd value in the table `contents` but I get this error `12: attempt to index global 'contents' (a nil value)`

```
function func(contents)
  print(contents[1])
  return contents
end

func({"content1", "content2", "content3"})
print(contents[2])
```

Comment: how can I make contents global

Comment: Do: ```contents = func({"content1", "content2", "content3"})```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can I make contents global

Function parameter `contents` is local to `func` and is shadowing any variable named `contents` in a bigger scope.

A global variable name is just referring to a field in table `_G`.
So in your function you could do

```
_G.contents = contents
```

But usually you avoid using global variables wherever possible.

As `func` returns `contents` simply do

```
print(func({"content1", "content2", "content3"})[2])
```

Answer (score 1):

If your function will always use the global variable, create the global variable and don't take it as an argument to the function:

```lua
contents = {"content1", "content2", "content3"}

function func()
  print(contents[1])
  print(#contents)
  return contents
end

func()
print(contents[2])
```

If you do want to have a global variables, I'd suggest renaming your argument to avoid confusion.  As this seems to just be a sample and your table seems to contain strings, I'll rename the argument 'strings' and show you can use the return value or the global variable ([repl.it](https://replit.com/@JasonGoemaat/MintcreamThisRate#main.lua)):

```lua
contents = {"content1", "content2", "content3"}

function func(strings)
  print(strings[1])
  print(#strings)
  return strings
end

local result = func(contents)
print(contents[2])
print(result[2])
```

Using global variables is frowned upon, you can make it local to your module and use it anywhere in your module by putting 'local' in front:

```lua
local contents = {"content1", "content2", "content3"}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However this seems a bit too exaggerated compared to how simply the parameter can be set global when table _G is used

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have the `print(contents[2])` outside of the function. `contents` is local to the function only. According to the rest of the program `contents` does not exist thus it is throwing an error. There is no global variable `contents` and it is saying `12:` which tells you the error is on line 12, which again, has the `print(contents[2])`